# how to add click event for newly appended div in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this is my html

```
 <div id="main">
    <div class="submit">welcome</div>
 </div>
```

this is my jquery

```
 $(".submit").click(function()
 {
     $("$main").append('<div class="submit">welcome</div>');

 });
```

here what happen this is working for first div .This event is not working for newly added div ?

how to solve this ?

Comment: `$("#main").on('click', '.submit', function () {
    $("#main").append('<div class="submit">welcome</div>');
});`

Comment: Simply remove $ from js and add # sign. like $("#main").append

Answer (score 5):

You've two options, delegation (assigning the click-handler to be detected by the parent):

```
$('#main').on('click', 'div.submit', function(){
    // this is your click-handler
});
```

Or by binding the click-handler at the point of element-creation:

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
    $('<div />', {
        'class' : 'submit',
        'on' : {
            'click' : function(){
                // this is your click-handler
            }
        }).appendTo('#main');

});
```

Obviously, if you have a named-function to call you can assign that instead of using the anonymous function:

```
$('#main').on('click', 'div.submit', namedFunctionToCall);
```

Or:

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
    $('<div />', {
        'class' : 'submit',
        'click' :  namedFunctionToCall
        }).appendTo('#main');

});
```

References:

- [Creating elements, with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

Use delegation:

```
$("#main").on("click", ".submit", function()
{
    $("#main").append('<div class="submit">welcome</div>');
});
```

And replace the `$` with `#` when selecting `#main`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
$("#main").on('click', '.submit', function () {
    $("#main").append('<div class="submit">welcome</div>');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nRLVg/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define # if your using div id like

```
$("#main").append();
```

In case if your using class it can be access by . like that

```
$(".main").append();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $('.submit').bind('click', function (event) {
       alert("Hello");
     });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use live Function

```
 $( ".submit" ).live( "click", function() {
  alert("Appended" ); // jQuery 1.3+
});
```

Comment: [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated in 1.7 (in favour of [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)), and removed in 1.9 (I'm not necessarily criticising your answer, just pointing out that `live()` may not (be able to) work depending on the version of jQuery used). Also, where `live()` is available, [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) is recommended by the jQuery team.